# Pollard's Kangaroo: How random does $f$ have to be?

Tags: hash, discrete-logarithm, pollard-rho

I'm implementing Pollard's kangaroo algorithm as described [here](https://people.math.gatech.edu/~tetali/PUBLIS/plambda031709.pdf).

[Wikipedia's description](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pollard%27s_kangaroo_algorithm) of the protocol says that you should have "a pseudorandom map $f:G\rightarrow S$."

Does anyone know what happens if you weaken the properties of the map? I'm trying to implement this (don't worry, it's for research--nothing nefarious) so a full hash function like SHA-256 seems like overkill in this situation (especially since $S$ is so small). Has anyone mathematically analyzed what would happen if you use something that is a bit weaker than a full-fledged Random-Oracle-like hash-function? Heuristically, I'm finding that even something ratched like using $f(p) = S[p.y \bmod |S|]$ when $G$ is an elliptic curve group does not seem to recognizably affect the number of hops before the wild kangaroo is caught.

Comment: Modeling $f$ as random is useful for runtime analysis, but in practice you can get away with simpler functions. See Section 3.4 of [Bai and Brent](https://maths-people.anu.edu.au/~brent/pd/rpb231.pdf) for some performance comparisons of different partitionings when using various random walks.